# Reading string from a file and saving in 2D array

Tags: arrays, c

I want to read some strings from a text file and save them into a 2D array of char like this:

```
FILE *fp;
int i = 0;
char word[20][20];

void text_reader();

int main () {
    fp = fopen("game.txt" , "r");
    text_reader();
    text_reader();
    printf("%s", word[i][20])
    return(0);
}

void text_reader(){
    char str[20];
    if( fgets (str, 150, fp) != NULL ) {
        str[strlen(str)-1] = '\0';
        strcpy(word[i][20], str[20]);
    }
    i++;
}
```

In game.txt, I have two lines and two words, and because of fgets(), removing the \n at the end of each line i wrote str[strlen(str)-1] = '\0'; , my second word in second line just doesn't get printed as I expected. Either helping me in this case or helping me to know how to get texts from a file and saving it in a 2D array would be what I'm looking for and I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: I've included needed libraries

Comment: You should include an example of your text file's content and show how your code fails (what does it result in?)

Comment: In `char str[20]; fgets(str, 150, ...)`...why are you using `150` instead of `20`?  The buffer can only hold 20 characters (19 plus the terminating null), not 150.  Use `fgets(str, sizeof str, ...`

Comment: Surely you get a compiler warning/error from `strcpy(word[i][20], str[20]);`. If not, turn up the diagnostics.

Comment: ok I edited that, and the game.txt = two lines, each line contains a word and the current error is : (null)

Comment: Welcome! Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as text, the shortest *complete* code that shows what you have tried. The best way to do that is by copy/paste, after you check it compiles and does exhibit the behaviour described. May I suggest you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please don't make rolling updates to coding errors - only to post the *actual* code you are asking about.

Comment: ... please don't *keep* making corrections to the posted code, because comments about the original won't make any sense. BTW I get one compiler error and 5 warnings.